# All possible Combinations of 5 variables that can take 3 values

Tags: combinatorics

I have five variables which can take three values as shown below

```
V1 = {1,2,3}, V2 = {1,2,3}, V3 = {1,2,3}, V4 = {1,2,3}, and V5 = {1,2,3}
```

Then how many rows following table can have if we want to have all possible combinations. Is it $3^5 = 243$? If so, then how to populate the following table with its all values?

```
         V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
 Row 1    1  1   1   1   1
 Row 2    2  1   1   1   1
 Row 3    3  1   1   1   1
 ...      .  .   .   .   .
 ...      .  .   .   .   .
Row 242   2  3   3   3   3
Row 243   3  3   3   3   3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it $3^5 = 243$?

Yes. All combinations of pairs of triplet values is $9$ values: imagine a $3\times 3$ grid with each cell representing a pairwise combination. Three random variables with three values each is a $3\times 3\times 3$ cube. Progressing to the case of $5$, we have $3^5$.

We can enumerate all of the combinations in R: `expand.grid(1:3,1:3,1:3,1:3,1:3)`. We see that the result has the predicted number of rows.

Comment: How to populate the table with its all values?

Comment: I've added to my answer.

Comment: I do not know how to use R, is it possible to generate this matrix in matlab? if yes, then how?

Comment: Done. I used this http://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/Rweb/ online interface to perform this task.

Comment: In general, it's best to specify what software you're using up front, since there are literally thousands of options and not very many people are psychic.